# Style of RadioButton magically changes when put into a Listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-radiobutton

I made a `DialogFragment` with a `RadioButton` ontop and a `ListView` below containing more `RadioButton`s. And now I'm just wondering what style the `ListView` uses that the `RadioButton`s don't look the same as the "stand-alone" one.

Here is a snippet of my dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/none" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/conferences"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my list_item.xml that I inflate as the rows in `getView` of my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/conference"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

My `AppTheme` is based on `"Theme.AppCompat"`. I didn't change any style of a specific item in my View.

The "stand-alone" `RadioButton` has a white circle with a blue dot when selected and even has a different style while you press it down. The `RadioButton`s in the `ListView` are all black with a black dot and don't have a "press-down" style. It would be cool if I wouldn't need to programatically set styles for not checked/"press-down"/checked. I already tried to set 2 base Android themes that had "RadioButton" in their names on the `ListView` but nothing changed. Maybe there is a way to get the style of the "stand-alone" `RadioButton` and set it in the xml files for the other `RadioButton`s?

I would post an image but I'm new here so not already allowed to do this.

**Update**

I changed my AppTheme to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RadioButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large</item>
</style>
```

And the `RadioButton`s in the `ListView` changed but not the "stand-alone" one. When I add the style to the `RadioButton`:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/none"
    style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/none" />
```

the text changes but the RadioButton-circle is still there. For the `RadioButton`s in the `ListView` the circles are gone...

Comment: "I would post an image but I'm new here so not already allowed to do this" -- you are welcome to upload an image elsewhere and link to it from your question. Beyond that, please post the code for your `ListAdapter` where you are using this layout.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about adding a link ;D

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `LayoutInflater` in your `Adapter` uses `Activity` context and not the application context.

**Update:**

Please remove `android` prefix from your style:

```
  <item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
```

And update `RadioButtonStyle` as follows:

```
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton" />
```

Comment: It does but I found something out... I've added an update to my post.

Comment: I am sorry for my late response. I tried this but that didn't change anything... So I added the android prefix again and set parent to "@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton" but still no change. I added <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item> to my RadioButtonStyle and at least the text changes for ALL RadioButtons (although I still have to add the style manually to the single RadioButton). But the circle is still different between standalone and listview radiobuttons